# Who has imago-machines and how common are they?

Tags: teixcalaan

I started reading *[A Memory Called Empire](https://www.arkadymartine.net/books/amce)* and I'm unsure of the prevalence of imagos and their background. Are they for Lsel (Stationers?) only, or do Teixcaalanis have some as well? Are they common among Stationers, or just for ambassadors and other governmental officials?

Answer (score 2):

**Imago machines are only for Lsel citizens (not just folks on the main station); they are a state secret, and Teixcalaani have a prejudice against the concept of self-improvement by that kind of means anyway.**

Here's where Mahit admits that it's treason to tell Imperials about imagos:

> “What does the implant do, Ambassador?”
>
> Hey, Yskandr, Mahit thought, reaching for the silence where the imago
> should be, watch me. I can commit sedition too.
>
> “It makes a record,” she said. “A copy. A person’s memories and their
> patterns of thought. We call it an imago-machine, because it makes an
> imago, a version of the person that outlives their body.

And here's what the Empire thinks of it:

> “So much of who we are is what we remember and retell,” said Three
> Seagrass. “Who we model ourselves on, which epic, which poem.
> Neurological enhancements are cheating.”

As far as how common imago machines are and who they are for, the book talks about pilot-lineages, so ambassadors and governmental figures are not the only ones with imago machines. They are fairly common though

> Even on a station of thirty thousand souls, and ten thousand preserved
> imago-lines alongside and within them, the entire storage facility for
> the machines is one small and sterile sphere of a room.

Not all the lineages are in current use - but still 10,000 lineages for perhaps 200,000 people (Lsel station is the largest of 10 stations) makes it likely that everyone knows a teacher, pilot or senior miner with an imago.

Comment: I had the impression that essentially all pilots had one, eventually if not initialily.

Comment: I think that's right